# Very ample line bundles and global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

my question concerns a very ample line bundle $L$ on a projective k-scheme.
It gives a closed immersion

$i:X \rightarrow P^{N-1}_{k}$

to some projective space over k.

It can be viewed as induced by global sections $s_
1,...,s_N$ of $L$.

Why do people always say that these sections form a basis of $H^{o}(X,L)$?
Surely they generate $L$ in the sense of: generating in every stalk.
But why is $N=dim(H^{o}(X,L)$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Descartes: This isn't true (take $X$ a point, for instance; then the pull-back $L$ of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the trivial line bundle and has only one section).

Comment: The morphism $i$ is given by $x\in X \mapsto [s_1(x): \cdots : s_N(x)]$ by definition, where $(s_i)$ is a basis of $H^0(X,L)$. So *by definition*, $i$ goes from $X$ to $\mathbb P^{N-1}$ (with your notations). Note that this morphism does depend on a choice of a basis, but all such images of $X$ under $i$ are conjugated by an element of $PGL_N$. A more intrisic way to define $i$ is to set $i(x)=\mathrm{Ker}(s\mapsto s(x))$ which defines $i:X\to \mathbb P(H^0(X,L)^*)$.

Comment: Dear Descartes, your notation seems incoherent. Either call your sections $s_0,...,s_N$ or take $\mathbb P^{N-1}$ as codomain of  your immersion (as correctly did Henri).

Comment: Dear Akhil, I'm not sure I understand your objection. If $X$ is a point, then it gets embedded into $\mathbb P^0_k$. Is Descartes's  slight confusion betwen $N$ and $N-1$ which you are hinting at?

Comment: Sorry about that confustion, I already corrected it.

Comment: Being globally generated corresponds to a surjection of sheaves $\pi:\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus N}\twoheadrightarrow L$. Being surjective on global sections corresponds to vanishing higher cohomology, so the sections $s_1,\ldots,s_N$ will generate $L(X)$ if and only if $H^1(\ker(\pi))=0$ if and only if $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus N})\hookrightarrow H^1(L)$.